# Not sure how to integrate Meteor and Jest when applying Jest framework to a Meteor project

Tags: meteor, jestjs

I have a Meteor project, with redux applied. Its folder structure listed bellow

```
+-lib
   +-ui (front-end codes)
+-server (back-end codes)
```

Since I can't change the folder structure to put everything in the src folder for Jest for Meteor doesn't allow my doing so, I am wondering if there are good solutions to this issue?

I guess it may have something to do with jest.config.js, but I am not sure. Plus, I am confused by the roles played by jest.config.js and setupTest.js--they look similar to me.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Things become clearer after I found a tutorial on https://alligator.io/react/testing-react-components/